# Add my resume as a PDF file to a Pelican static blog site

Tags: python, github, blogs, github-pages, pelican

I have a personal blog which I build with pelican and used [Elegant](https://github.com/Pelican-Elegant/elegant). Here are the source and site repos: [source](https://github.com/Okroshiashvili/Data-Science-Fabric) and [site](https://github.com/Okroshiashvili/Okroshiashvili.github.io).

Now I want to add my resume or CV as a separate category or page.
Expected setup should be. "Home", "Categories", "Tags", "Archives", and "Resume"

Expected output should be: when visitor click resume page it should open as a pdf file showing my resume or CV.

I tried a lot but without any success. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a pdf here: `content/images/resume.pdf`

Then add a link to it in your header (in `pelican-themes/elegant/templates/base.html`). Underneath the following block:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
```

You'll see a bunch of `<li>` tags, e.g.:

```
<li {% if page_name == 'archives' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ ARCHIVES_URL|default('archives') }}">Archives</a></li>
```

Add `<li><a href='images/my.pdf'></a></li>` below the Archives link referenced above and rebuild your site.

Comment: I tried this way but still does not work. I added ```<li><a href='images/my.pdf'></a></li>``` and rebuild locally but did not work. After that, I added ```<li><a href='../../../content/images/resume.pdf'></a></li>``` but this does not work too. I rebuild the site locally and that's why this does not work? or it does not matter?

Comment: To simplify, just upload your pdf to Amazon S3, then provide the link in your header `<li><a href='https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/resume.pdf'></a></li>`. Let me know when you get that set...

Comment: The correct link is this                                                                                  
 ```<li><a href='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/resume.pdf'>Resume</a></li>```                 
 as you see it needed the name. Thanks a lot. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, some buckets use that prefix. I'm glad it all worked out!

Comment: You can add it directly to one of your markup pages like this:
`[My Resume]({static}/pdfs/resume.pdf)`. Mind you that I had  to create the pdfs folder under content and put it there, the images folder didn't work.